# Symfony 5 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] after send project on hosting

Tags: symfony

I just send my project in symfony 5 on hosting and i have error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Or if i want execute:

```
php74-cli bin/console make:migration

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddr
  esses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known


In Exception.php line 18:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name o
  r service not known


In PDOConnection.php line 37:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name o
  r service not known


In PDOConnection.php line 37:

  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or s
  ervice not known
```

What do i need to change besides changing the data for connection in the file .env ?

I make simple php file to check my data for connections and it works, but in symfony not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a good practice to generate the .env.prod file on the server /which you don’t commit in your git repository/ with the actual connection to the production DB an the execute on the server

```
composer dump-env prod
```

Comment: execute this and i have some errors: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv::populate() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Dotenv\void, none returned in /home/serwer2011270/public_html/portfolio5/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:222 Stack trace:
#0 home/serwer2011270/public_html/portfolio5/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(568): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->populate(Array, false)
#1/home/serwer2011270/public_html/portfolio5/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(92): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad(false, Array)`

Comment: `#2/home/serwer2011270/public_html/portfolio5/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(114): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load('./.env')
#3/home/serwer2011270/public_html/portfolio5/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Command/DumpEnvCommand.php(94): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->loadEnv('./.env')
#4/home/serwer2011270/public_html/portfolio5/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Command/DumpEnvCommand.php(53): Symfony\Flex\Command\DumpEnvCommand->loadEnv('./.env', 'prod')
#5 phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console in /home/serwer2011270/public_html/portfolio5/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 222`

Comment: You need the .env as well. The .env.prod just need to contain the overrides of .env

Comment: Just read here for reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#common-post-deployment-tasks

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is? In .env file ? Or maybe in connection ? I generate .env.local.php file on my local pc and send on hosting : `return array (
  'APP_ENV' => 'dev',
  'APP_SECRET' => '#########',
  'DATABASE_URL' => 'mysql://myuser:mypass@myhost.home.pl/mydbname',
);
` Meybe here is error ? On my local pc project i have : `?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11` Here i nedd server version too ? 
On this hosting it's hard to do any ssh command so I don't know if everything is going well

Comment: Any firewall on the DB?

Comment: Hmm i don;t know everything is on hosting, server www, mysql database, mail server etc.

Comment: Does the simple php file to test the connection work on the server?

Comment: Yes i make this: `$servername = "myhost.home.pl";
$username = "myuser";
$password = "mypass";
$dbname = 'mydbname';

// Create connection
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

$q = "SELECT * FROM testtable";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
echo "base check<br><br>";
var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));` and I have a valid query result. I use the same user,pass and dbname here and in symfony.

Comment: Try this `composer install —no-dev && composer dump-autoload —optimize —no-dev —classmap-authoritative —no-interaction && php bin/console cache:warmup && composer dump-env prod` adjust the paths for you server

Comment: Wherever i execute this command i have error: `Invalid argument —no-dev. Use "composer require —no-dev" instead to add packages to your composer.json.` On server or on my local pc.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution ! I have # in my password to mysql base I change it and connection works !

Comment: That was waste of time.. however I’m glad that you resolved the issue